# task scheduler to be used for php programs?

Tags: php, scheduling

Is there any free or open source task scheduler that I will use in PHP code? Secondly it should work for all PHP frameworks.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What do you mean by "task scheduler"? Something like Cron? I wonder how that should work. PHP applications I know (eg. ownCloud) revert to Cron for scheduling, and I guess they've got a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use cron on Linux and or Task Scheduler on Windows? I've used it in the past and there are a lot of guides online to follow.